# Does a whisper gnome count as a gnome for meeting feats' prerequisites?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, races

Two feats in *Races of Stone* have as one of their prerequisites being a whisper gnome. This made me wonder: Does a whisper gnome count as a (generic, untyped) gnome for meeting prerequisites or is whisper gnome an entirely different race from (generic, untyped) gnome and unable to meet (generic, untyped) gnome prerequisite?

Comment: @GreedyRadish It would not; he’s asking about feats like Burrow Friend (*Races of Stone* pg. 137) that include “**Prerequisites:** Gnome,” in them. All such feats would share the same answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## All gnomes have a subrace like rock or whisper

There's no such thing as a gnome *without* a subrace. Although not called out as such by the *Player's Handbook* (16-17), the gnome race described therein is the rock gnome, "the most common variety" of gnome (*Monster Manual* 131), and the game includes a fairly large number of gnome subraces, yet the larger classification—the gnome *race* (and, perhaps, *kind*, what *PH* 310 calls a "subcategory of creature")—encompasses *all* gnomes in its warm, gnomish embrace.

This means both a whisper gnome and a rock gnome and any other kind of gnome are *all* broadly gnomes. This also means a whisper gnome can meet the prerequisites of feats that include gnome *and* whisper gnome, but a whisper gnome *can't* meet a feat's prerequisite if the feat's prerequisite were *rock gnome* like the feat Rock Gnome Trickster (*Races of Faerûn* 167). (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49060/8610).)

Just in case further proof is needed, the *Exemplars of Evil* NPC Draen Ralgael is a wererat whisper gnome rogue whose subtypes include gnome (52-3).

Comment: Amusingly, Draen pops up again in *Elder Evils* (129), both by [Robert J. Schwalb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_J._Schwalb).

Comment: That's perfect, thanks to all who answered. I thought that your explanation would be the case but didn't want to go ahead & make assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

Having the gnome subtype would be sufficient for whisper gnomes to qualify as gnomes for feats and prestige classes. *Races of Destiny* talks about how the human subtype would do this for half-human races, and certainly all the elf subraces in Forgotten Realms can use elf feats and prestige classes.

The problem is that we don’t have any example whisper gnome statblocks, which means we don’t *explicitly* know that it has the gnome subtype. I think it’s only reasonable to assume that they do, but nothing comes out and says it.

Also, for the record, the race listed as “gnome” in the *Player’s Handbook* is actually a rock gnome. The *Monster Manual* (i.e. also core) includes the forest gnome as well. Both have the gnome subtype, and the rock gnome, clearly, meets any “Gnome” prerequisites. The forest gnome should as well, and thus I’d say that whisper gnome also does.

As far as consensus, whisper gnomes are widely recommended online for stealth; their racial features are excellent for it. No one in these discussions considers them restricted from taking gnome-only feats and prestige classes. In the [Shadowcraft Mage Handbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=5638.0), about a gnome-only prestige class, both whisper gnomes and forest gnomes are considered (in this case, the forest or rock gnomes’ +1 to Illusion DCs generally trumps anything that whisper gnomes offer, but still, no one was saying you *can’t*). And certainly in any discussion of racial-specific options, consideration of subraces is often an important part of the conversation.