# How does a ranger take shades as his favored enemy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, class-feature, prestige-class

The *Player's Handbook* on [favored enemy](http://dndsrd.net/ranger.html#ranger-favored-enemy) says, "If the ranger chooses humanoids or outsiders as a favored enemy, he must also choose an associated subtype, as indicated on the table" (47). The *PH* then goes on to list some available outsider subtypes like air, chaotic, earth, and evil. A ranger can't pick *just* outsiders and stab better *every* outsider from [tritons](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#triton) to [titans](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#titan), for instance.

The prestige class shade hunter (*Champions of Ruin* 58-63) has as a special requirement for entry *[shades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shade_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) as a favored enemy*. The *Races of Faerûn* description of shades says, "As creatures of the Plane of Shadow, shades are considered to be of the outsider type" (148), but that text doesn't mention shades as having *any* subtypes! Published characters seem to be of little help. For example, neither *Anaruoch*'s shade Keevosen Nihili (31) nor *City of Splendors: Waterdeep*'s Alauneth “the Black Viper” Orrane (69-70) has a subtype that would allow shades as a ranger's favored enemy pick.

Did shades ever receive one or more subtypes? If not, is there an official way that a creature can gain shades as a favored enemy so that a creature *can* enter the prestige class shade hunter, or must the DM make a house rule so that a creature can meet this prestige class's requirements?

---

***Note:*** I know, "Who cares?" right? A level 4 shade hunter gains the relatively unique and seemingly natural ability tools of the trade, allowing the shade hunter to root around in his gear and "find" mundane items of his choosing that were previously not recorded among the shade hunter's gear, a special ability of which I am particularly fond. While a similar ability can be gained from the Dragon *#354 feat Packrat (56) (with its hard-to-get-by-the-DM prerequisites) and from the extraordinary ability resourceful search of the* Races of Destiny *prestige class menacing brute (123-6), the shade hunter's is the more versatile and interesting. Alternatives to these three options for being able to mundanely produce gear instantaneously are appreciated but beyond this question's scope.*

Comment: Just in case anyone else puts a bunch of work into it before realising it doesn't matter, since shade is a template, the creature has the subtypes it had before it acquired the template, along with the Augmented subtype. The problem is, that doesn't make it possible to choose shades as a favored enemy - if you choose Outsider(Augmented human), *some* shades will be your favored enemy, but you won't have shades as your favored enemy.

Comment: Is shades a race? Races provide racial subtypes, at least according to some WotC authors.

Comment: @Chemus Sort of? I mean, shades are, so far as I can tell, closer an ill-defined [kind](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_kind&alpha=K) of outsider, much like a slaad or an arrowhawk is a *kind* of outsider. Unlike those creatures, though,—and, like I said, so far as I can tell—a typical shade doesn't usually doesn't have any subtypes *at all!* (This is different from, for example, a *subrace* like sun elf or a [whisper gnome](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87502/8610).)

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that shades are not a native outsider?

Comment: @fectin The text says that shades are "creatures of the Plane of Shadow" and doesn't *say* they have the subtype native. Further,—I just checked—neither published example has the subtype native, and both date to after the *3.5* revision. However, there's probably an argument to be made that *Races of Faerûn* dates to before the term's system-wide implementation and that later writers just—I dunno—forgot or something.

Comment: @HeyICanChan They (probably??) were native outsiders in 3.0, when "native" was a subtype you gained or lost depending on whether you were on your home plain.

Comment: @fectin I think there may be confusion in that comment over the subtype native and the subtype extraplanar. The extraplanar subtype is gained or lost depending upon the creature's current and home plane, but the subtype native is retained no matter what plane a creature's on (see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59021/8610)). I don't think there was a shift in that meaning with the *3.5* revision. The subtype native is a choice for an outsider favored enemy; the subtype extraplanar isn't.

Answer (score 12):

A 3.5e ranger can't, but a 3.0 ranger can. The trouble is that *Races of Faerûn* is a transitional product, having started development when the game was still D&D 3rd edition, and published the same year (2003) that D&D v3.5 was published. WotC has a history of letting these kinds of production pipeline problems just kinda… happen.

(The business alternative is to hold up a bunch of products, seriously messing with their delivery schedules, making distributors very unhappy and messing with everyone's cash flows. So it's understandable that they would let these kinds of transitional problems just slide.)

In D&D 3e, rangers simply choose a “type” of creature, with the following explanatory wording indicating that this wasn't any kind of game-rule **type** being invoked, just the fuzzy-logic human conceptual ability to tell *kinds* of things apart:

> At 1st level, a ranger may select a type of creature (dragons, giants, goblinoids, undead, etc.) as a favored enemy. (A ranger can only select his own race as a favored enemy if he is evil.)

This loosely-defined ability didn't survive the .5 update, but *Races of Faerûn* wasn't updated. In 3.0 it's trivial to have shades as a favoured enemy — you just choose “shades” — which is why the PrC is worded that way.

Porting this *properly* to 3.5e will require some judgement and shimming. You could simply say that the existence of the PrC somehow magically allows 3.5e rangers to select shades as a favoured enemy somehow, as some kind of backwards-working addition to the ranger's set of selectable favoured enemies. More complex would be to house rule that the shades template adds the subtype **shades**. Either way, the PrC just isn't fully 3.5e-compatible and needs some work.

Comment: While *Races* is a *3e* book, *Champions of Ruin* isn't, and that's this prestige class's source. In fact, *Champions of Ruin* appears *2 years* after the *3.5* revision. Further, almost all of Faerûn's *3e* creatures were updated by a *Player's Guide to Faerûn* Web enhancement, but, seemingly, not *this* creature, and I want to make sure that I didn't just miss it or that an update isn't lurking in a sidebar or online or something. (That's not to dismiss your answer but to encourage others to keep looking!)

Answer (score 0):

#### A DM using a variant rule from *Masters of the Wild* may allow a ranger to have unsubtyped outsiders as a favored enemy

As d7's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88962/8610) mentions, *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* has slightly different rules for the [ranger](http://www.dragon.ee/30srd/ranger.htm)'s favored enemy than does the *3.5* revision of the ranger's [favored enemy](http://dndsrd.net/ranger.html#ranger-favored-enemy), *Third Edition* expecting a ranger to pick, for example, barbed devil or pit fiend rather than a subtype like baatezu, evil, or lawful. Probably already in progress while the *3.5* revision took place, the *Player's Guide to Faerûn* was still likely working from *Third Edition* rules, expecting PCs to pick shades instead of, for example, ice devils. Why *Champions of Ruin*—published over a year after the *3.5* revision—does not explain how a *3.5* ranger can gain shades as a favored enemy, however, is a mystery.

That said, *Masters of the Wild*—a *Third Edition* text—describes Variant Favored Enemy Rules, saying

> Some favored enemy choices have significantly less utility than others—namely outsiders and those types that are immune to critical hits. The variant rules presented here make these choices more appealing. As with all variant rules, a player wishing to utilize these must first get the DM’s consent.
>
> #### Favoring Subtypes of Outsiders
>
> In this variant, the ranger can choose a subtype of outsider as a favored enemy. **The available options are** air, chaotic, earth, evil, fire, good, lawful, water, and **no subtype**. A ranger… who chooses outsiders with no subtype gains bonuses against aasimars, half-celestials, half-fiends, jann, ravids, and tieflings. (18)

(Emphasis mine, and reformatted for clarity.) As the *3.5* revision already incorporates *most* of this variant, it's trivial for the DM to include among the *3.5* revision's ranger's favored enemy the option to pick as a favored enemy outsiders that have *no* subtypes, like the (confusing and inconsistent) shade.

Note that the *3.5* revision to the *Monster Manual* adds the subtype native to the aasimar (209), [janni](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#janni) (116), and tiefling (209-10), and the subtype extraplanar to the ravid (213-4), and says under the templates' Type and Subtype that creatures possessing the template [half-celestial](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#half-celestial) (144-6) or [half-fiend](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#half-fiend) (147-9) are "normally native outsiders." This means, I guess, that, technically, *abnormal* half-outsiders without the subytype native and shades will be some of the *only* creatures such a ranger's favored enemy bonuses will apply to if the ranger is allowed to pick—without subtypes—favored enemy (outsiders).

Since that sucks, this DM would likely allow a ranger that picked favored enemy (outsiders) to gain his favored enemy bonus against any creature that possesses both the type outsider and *either* no subtype *or* the [extraplanar](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#extraplanar) or [native](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#native) subtypes so as to include those creatures listed in *Masters of the Wild* as well as, for example, the [shadow mastiff](http://dndsrd.net/monstersS.html#shadow-mastiff) (*MM* 222). Really, specializing in killing such creatures makes about as much sense as specializing in killing, for example, aberrations or magical beasts—both of which are already available and impossibly diverse—, so this shouldn't be that big of a deal.