# Does a race that is a sub-variant of another one qualify for feats restricted to members of that race?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, feat-qualifications

Does a character being a race that is described as a sub-variant of another - *for example, [Svirfneblin](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Svirfneblin) to [Gnome](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Gnome)* - qualify said character to take feats that are restricted to members of the super-race (for want of a better term) - *for example, [Earth Child Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/earth-child-style-combat-style/)* - due to sharing a sub-type?

Comment: Although it's for *3.5* you may nonetheless be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87502/8610)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

According to the [Advanced Race Guide](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Humanoid%20(0%20RP)&Category=Type%20Quality):

> Every humanoid creature also has a subtype to match its race, such as human, giant, goblinoid, reptilian, or tengu. If you are making a new humanoid race, you should either find an existing subtype to match or make a new one by using the name of the race as the subtype. If you are making a halfbreed race, it should have the racial type of both parent races. For example, a half-elf has both the human and the elf subtypes. Subtypes are often important to qualify for other racial abilities and feats. **If a humanoid has a racial subtype, it is considered a member of that race in the case of race prerequisites.**

This passage from the race creation rules should settle matters conclusively.

As for your example, since [Svirfneblin](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Svirfneblin) are Humanoids with the "Gnome" subtype, they qualify for all character options that have "Gnome" as a prerequisite just like a "normal" Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

You only qualify as a member of that "super-race" for purposes of taking race-based options if you have [an ability that says so](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125918/does-having-the-elf-subtype-qualify-you-for-character-options-which-require-yo) (like a half-elf's Elf Blood trait or the Racial Heritage feat).

Note that you *do* still qualify as a member of that "super-race" for effects that care about type and subtype, like a ranger's Favored Enemy.

Comment: Does there exist rules text that explicitly states that prerequisites such as *”be a Gnome”* are satisfied by having the gnome subtype?

Comment: @royalmurder Good question!  In fact, turns out I've been playing it wrong for quite some time-- have edited my answer accordingly.